# GLSL: Getting minimum resolvable difference for a depth buffer

Tags: opengl-es

I would like to move vertices in a GLSL shader in a way that they are guaranteed to be in front of other vertices with the smallest move necessary. Is there a portable way to extract this value for a given depth buffer attachment either from within the vertex shader or from CPU side so I can send it to the shader as a constant? Method should be compatible with GLES 3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking for, but have you looked at [`glPolygonOffset`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glPolygonOffset.xhtml)` already?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is that this would require the decals to be in a separate drawcall and I don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a portable way to extract this value for a given depth buffer attachment from within the vertex shader or from CPU side so I can send it to the shader as a constant?

This isn't really how GPUs work.

Vertex shading doesn't know about triangles or any of the fragment stage operations. At the point in time you are shading your vertices the current framebuffer depth doesn't even exist - especially on tile-based GPUs commonly found on mobile - so you cannot know what you are supposed to be "in front of".

The CPU side idea is even worse - you'd need to know this at the point you are submitting your draw calls and at that point you have no idea where anything is - all of your mesh data will be in object space.

Also worth noting that the minimum resolvable distance is not a constant. It's non linear and the distribution of values depends on the near and far clip position in the perspective transform, and the depth of the actual location.